# How to open a tkinter and shell script at once?

Tags: python, tkinter

My normal script is called `start.py`

The code is this:

```
inp = input("Select:")

if inp == '1':
 print("1")
elif inp == '2':
 print("2")
else:
 print("error")
```

now I got a tkinter window that I want to start with the input script together.

Now my code looks like this:

```
os.system("python tkinterwindow.py")
inp = input("Select:")

if inp == '1':
 print("1")
elif inp == '2':
 print("2")
else:
 print("error")
```

Now the Problem is:

Both are opening but the input is only displayed, if I close the tkinter window.

How can I run both and use both at the same time?

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `os.system()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use multithreading where one thread handles the Tkinter GUI and another handles the CLI.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # Put whatever you want for the Tkinter window.
        self.window = Tk()

        Label(self.window, text="Tkinter GUI").pack()

        mainloop()

class CLI:
    def __init__(self):
        # Put whatever you wanted for the shell script.
        while True:
            inp = input("Select...")
            if inp == "1":
                print("1")
            elif inp == "2":
                print("2")
            else:
                print("error")

Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=GUI)
Thread1.start()

Thread2 = threading.Thread(target=CLI)
Thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a multithreaded approach:

```py
inp = ""

def take_input():
    global inp
    inp = input("Select:")
    

threading.Thread(target=take_input).start()
os.system("python tkinterwindow.py")
```